# Upload and download of files using PaperClip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have a question that I do not really not how to answer .. 
I would like my users to be able to upload and download midi files from the website.

For the upload no problem I used paperClip gem. My issue is for the download link I dont know how to do it ...
I tried a few things but the results give me just an url type ..

Could you help me ?

Thx you so much for your help!

Raphael

Comment: Placing an url as the target of an anchor tag?

Comment: hey ;-) what do you mean ? I tried that <%= @midi.middiz.url %> but it does not work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is as simple as trying this:

```
<%= link_to @midi.middiz.filename, @midi.middiz.url %>
```

It will create an anchor tag pointing to the file to be downloaded.

Comment: Thx you so much ;-) I am learning rails and sometimes ( most of the time ... ) it makes sense to me only when I get the answer ..